# 'My better days is at the last decade' make sense?

Tags: grammar

Does a sentence like

> My better days, at the last decade, have passed by so fast.

make sense?

Comment: **At** is used with a moment in time, not with a time-span.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Using 'throughout','during', or 'in' give the phrase the meaning that your better days are spread out in the decade interval:

My better days, throughout the last decade, have passed by so fast.

'At' has the sense of a single point in time, in this case a single point during a ten year span, which is not aligned with the meaning of your sentence.